# How do I apply CountVectorizer to each row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe say df which has 3 columns. Column A and B are some strings. Column C is a numeric variable. 
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRXs9.png)

I want to convert this to a feature matrix by passing it to a CountVectorizer.

I define my countVectorizer as:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(input='content', encoding='iso-8859-1', 
                     decode_error='ignore', analyzer='word',
                    ngram_range=(1), tokenizer=my_tokenizer, stop_words='english',
                    binary=True)
```

Next I pass the entire dataframe to cv.fit_transform(df) which doesn't work.
I get this error:
cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Next I covert each row of the dataframe to

```
sample = pdt_items["A"] + "," + pdt_items["C"].astype(str) + "," + pdt_items["B"]
```

Then I apply

```
cv_m = sample.apply(lambda row: cv.fit_transform(row))
```

I still get error:
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Please let me know where am I going wrong?Or if I need to take some other approach?

Comment: You need to share some data to make this a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have a great sense of what's in your df.

Comment: @mayosten I have added the image of a snippet of my dataset. Thanks!

Comment: datasetname and id are the indexes. JFYI.

Comment: @Shreya I am guessing what you want from my experiences working with NLP. Try cv_m = sample.apply(lambda row: cv.fit_transform(row.to_string()))

Comment: @QuantStats i got the following error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string'

Comment: @Shreya Have a look at my example with a minimal working example. You need to use pd.DataFrame() at line sample = ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

A = ['very good day', 'a random thought', 'maybe like this']
B = ['so fast and slow', 'the meaning of this', 'here you go']
C = [1, 2, 3]

pdt_items = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B,'C':C})

cv = CountVectorizer()

# use pd.DataFrame here to avoid your error and add your column name    
sample = pd.DataFrame(pdt_items['A']+','+pdt_items['B']+','+pdt_items['C'].astype('str'), columns=['Output'])

vectorized = cv.fit_transform(sample['Output'])
```

Comment: I tried this is 2 ways: First I just replaced A,B and C with the column names in my dataframe and used the code sample = pd.DataFrame(pdt_items['info']+','+pdt_items['manufacturer']+','+pdt_items['price'].astype('str'), columns=['Output']) I get the following error:TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
Next, I tried the way you have implemented: A = [pdt_items['info']],B = [pdt_items['manufacturer']], C= [pdt_items['price']]    test = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B,'C':C})   testsample = pd.DataFrame(test['A']+','+test['B']+','+test['C'].astype('str'), columns=['Output'])

Comment: and finally vectorized = cv.fit_transform(testsample['Output']) I got the following error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: pardon the formatting! the comment section doesn't allow me to enter the code in the next line.

Comment: @Shreya print(pdt_items['price']) I can help you if I know how it looks like. The first approach is more likely to succeed.

Comment: Hi, I have added an image of my dataframe in the original problem. You may have a look. It will have the values for price column too. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: @Shreya Try pdt_items = pdt_items.reset_index(), then perform your first method again.

Comment: @Shreya Actually try this for your second method, do A=pdt_items['info'].to_list(), B=pdt_items['manufacturer'].to_list(),C=pdt_items['manufacturer'].to_list() instead, then follow through.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @QuantStats's comment, I applied the cv on each row of dataframe as follows:

```
row_input = df['column_name'].tolist()

kwds = []
for i in range(len(row_input)):
  cell_input = [row_input[i]]
  full_set = row_keywords(cell_input, 1,1)
  candidates = [x for x in full_set if x[1]> 1] # to extract frequencies more than 1
  kwds.append(candidates)

kwds_col = pd.Series(kwds)
df['Keywords'] = kwds_col
```

("row_keywords" is a function for CountVectorizer.)